# Wait for a promise to complete before processing the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a service wrapping a 3rd-party API which I'm using to retrieve data into my controller. I'd like to do some processing to pivot the data before displaying it but I can't work how to make this happen *after* the promise has completed. Until then there's no data to process!

I've tried a couple of different ways but neither seems to work:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
        MyService.getData(myParams)
            .then(function (results) {
                $scope.queryResults = results;
                // Can't do processing here, data hasn't been retrieved yet
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.alerts.push({ msg: 'Unable to get data', type: 'danger' });
            });
    }

    $scope.$watch('queryResults', function(newVals) {
        // Can't do processing here either, this only fires at
        // "$scope.queryResults = results;"
        // above where "results" is still an empty array
    });
};
```

And the service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('MyService', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        getData: function (params) {
            var operation = $q.defer();
            ThirdPartyLibrary.getData(params, { callback: function(err, results) {
                if (err == null ) {
                    operation.resolve(results);
                } else {
                    operation.reject(err, results);
                }
            }});
            return operation.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

This must be a pretty common thing to want to do, but I can't find much on Google - although I'm probably searching for the wrong things!

**EDIT**

OK, so I've refactored a lot of things, and the underlying problem still seems to be that my promise chains are progressing before data is returned from earlier in the chain. Here's the new code:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('MyService', ['MyWrapperService', function(MyWrapperService) {
    var getDataForFilter = function(myApi, filter) {
        var processedResults = {};
        // This is the chain I'm having problems with
        return MyWrapperService.getRelevantKeys(myApi, filter).then(MyWrapperService.getDetailsForKeys).then(function(results){
            //do some processing here
            return processedResults;
        }, function(errors) {
            return errors;
        });
    };

    return {getDataForFilter: getDataForFilter};
}]);

angular.module('myApp').service('MyWrapperService', ['$q', function($q) {
    var getRelevantKeys = function(myApi, filter) {
        var operation = $q.defer();
        myApi.getKeys({'filter': filter, 'callback': function (err, results) {
            if (err == null) {
                    // This does get called correctly, but not until after the rest of the chain has been called.
                operation.resolve(myApi, results, filter);
            } else {
                operation.reject(err, results);
            }
        }
    };
    var getDetailsForKeys = function(myApi, keys, filter) {            
        var operation = $q.defer();
        var promises = [];
        var details = [];
        var errors = [];

        angular.forEach(keys, function (val) {
            // Get the data for each key. ***When this is called, 'keys' is still undefined.***
            promises.push(getDataForKey(myApi, val, filter).then(function(result){
                details.push(result);
            }, function(err, result) {
                errors.push(err);
            }));
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(function() {operation.resolve(details);}, function() {operation.reject(errors)});
        return operation.promise;
    };
    var getDataForKey = function(myApi, key, filter) {
        var operation = $q.defer();
        myApi.getDetail(key, {
            'filter': filter,
            'callback': function(err, results) {
                if (err == null) {
                    operation.resolve(myApi, results, activity);
                } else {
                    operation.reject(err, results);
                }
            }
        });
        return operation.promise;
    };

    return {
        getRelevantKeys: getRelevantKeys,
        getDetailsForKeys: getDetailsForKeys,
        getDataForKey: getDataForKey,
    };
}]);
```

Unfortunately the API makes what I'm trying to do a bit long-winded, but I'm getting all the database keys related to a filter, then getting all the values for those keys, then pivoting the data (the comment in `getDataForFilter`) before passing it back to the controller to display. I'm happy to add more comments if anything isn't clear.

(Also any general feedback on the architecture this would be much appreciated!)

Comment: "*this only fires at `$scope.queryResults = results;`*" is exactly what you wanted, isn't it? If `results` is an empty array, then that means that `getData` did result in an empty array.

Comment: I'm guessing it's your service that does something weird, or you just don't actually receive any data for the request you make.

Comment: It does return data, but it takes a few seconds to happen. `then(function (results) { $scope.queryResults = results; }` is called instantly with an empty array, which is then populated once the underlying API call completes.

Comment: Any chance you're using ui-router or ngRoute? You can resolve promises before displaying any content using them.

Comment: I'm using ui-router, although this action is triggered by a form submit rather than a state loading

Comment: So then MyService.getData returns the wrong promise. If you can post the code for it, it might shed some light into why it's happening.

Comment: Added the service code. The library uses explicit callback functions instead of promises, hence the use of $q.

Comment: clearly `ThirdPartyLibrary.getData` does not do what you think it does - any information about that library?

Comment: Assuming that's not a typo when you said it's using "callback functions", maybe you're not configuring the right callback then.

Comment: There's only one callback function, which fires correctly, but it only fires *after* code further down the chain has been called. I've refactored my code a lot to get rid of some of my nested promises too but still no luck. I'll update the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I completely refactored everything and now it all works! One of the problems was forgetting that `$q.resolve()` and `$q.reject()` are only able to return a single argument when I assumed that I could just return as many arguments as I wanted with them (as you can with anonymous functions) and later calls to `then()` would receive them all.

If anyone's interested, I'll post my code after refactoring but the minimum I needed to do was replace calls like this:

```
operation.resolve(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

with this:

```
operation.resolve({'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2, 'arg3':arg3});
```

and adjust the functions that take these arguments accordingly.